# Playstore Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

"**Action required **- One deep link may be failing because your web domains aren't associated with your app
This means that on Android 12 and above, your app can't accept traffic from some web URLs. To fix issues and make sure users go directly to your app, go to the Deep links page.

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nST6Z.jpg)

Help me to fix this issue"